# Negative Id values generation with GenerationType.SEQUENCE

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, entity, sequences

Why do I always get negative values of an entity id? Wheter it related with `increment` amount value? For example while I'm using

```
create sequence message_sequence start 1 increment 1;
```

I always get negative values (-38, -44, -45). But in case I'm putting

```
create sequence message_sequence start 1 increment 50;
```

It's all fine (52, 102). Why so weird behavior?
This is an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "messages")
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "message_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "message_sequence", sequenceName = "message_sequence")
    private long id;

    private String text;

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

programe entrance point:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = JPAUtility.getEntityManagerFactory();

EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();

entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

Message m = new Message();
m.setText("Hello World");

etityManager.persist(m);

entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
entityManager.close();
```

Comment: `select nextval('message_sequence');` generates positives. Please elaborate - I belive nobody will be able to reproduce it like above

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I have the same problem. ...

Answer (score 4):

In SequenceGenerator annotation there is a variable named allocationSize. This size is by default is 50. It means that Hibernate will reserve 50 ids and it will not need to retrieve new id for every insert. set the allocationSize=1 to resolve this issue for negetive value generation.

Answer (score 2):

After adding  `allocationSize = 1` code to `@SequenceGenerator`
working fine!